# how to get the list from calendar table and merge to attendance table and leave table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. I have a problem in merging tables. We have 500+ employees

I have the following tables:

1. `Calendar` table - holds the dates from 1/1/2005 to 12/31/2016
2. `Attendance` table - for the attendance of employees
3. `LeaveHistory` table - for the leave history
4. `LeaveBreakDown` table -for leave break down
5. `Holiday` table - for holidays

Our goal, with date range from calendar (11/1/2015 - 11/30/2015)
we want to show the complete days even if the attendance is not equal to the total numbers of days.

Here's my first solution but too slow and without calendar table

```
 FETCH NEXT FROM Employees INTO @EmployeeID,@BranchCode,@IsOfficer, @FirstName, @MiddleName, @LastName, @RankCode;

 WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
 BEGIN
     WHILE @StartDate <= @EndDate
     BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #tblData(ActualDate,EmployeeID,BranchCode,IsOfficer, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, RankCode, LeaveCode, Gender, ShiftCode,ShiftIn,ShiftOut,IsRestDay) 
            SELECT
                 @StartDate
                    , @EmployeeID
                    , @BranchCode
                    , @IsOfficer
                    , @FirstName
                    , @MiddleName
                    , @LastName
                    , @RankCode
                    , LB.LeaveBreakDownCode
                    , E.Gender
                ,ShiftCode = SS.ShiftCode
                ,ShiftIn = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), DATEADD(day,0,@StartDate), 101) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), SS.ShiftIn,108))
                ,ShiftOut = CASE
                                                                     WHEN SS.ShiftOut < SS.ShiftIn THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), DATEADD(day,1,@StartDate), 101) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), SS.ShiftOut ,108))
                                                                     ELSE CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), DATEADD(day,0,@StartDate), 101) + ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), SS.ShiftOut ,108))
                                                                END
                ,IsRestDay = CASE
                                                                            WHEN SS.Sunday = 1 AND DATEPART(weekday, @StartDate) = 1 THEN 1
                                                                            WHEN SS.Monday = 1 AND DATEPART(weekday, @StartDate) = 2 THEN 1
                                                                            WHEN SS.Tuesday = 1 AND DATEPART(weekday, @StartDate) = 3 THEN 1
                                                                            WHEN SS.Wednesday = 1 AND DATEPART(weekday, @StartDate) = 4 THEN 1
                                                                            WHEN SS.Thursday = 1 AND DATEPART(weekday, @StartDate) = 5 THEN 1
                                                                            WHEN SS.Friday = 1 AND DATEPART(weekday, @StartDate) = 6 THEN 1
                                                                            WHEN SS.Saturday = 1 AND DATEPART(weekday, @StartDate) = 7 THEN 1                      
                                                                            ELSE 0
                                                                        END
                    FROM Employees E
                    LEFT JOIN (
                        SELECT
                        LB.LeaveBreakDownCode
                        , LB.EmployeeID
                        FROM LeaveBreakDown LB
                        INNER JOIN LeaveHistory LH ON LH.LeaveHistoryCode = LB.LeaveHistoryCode AND LB.DateLeave = @StartDate AND LH.Status IN ('0','1')
                        WHERE LB.EmployeeID = @EmployeeID                                           
                    ) LB ON LB.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID                        
                    LEFT JOIN ShiftSchedule SS ON SS.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID AND @StartDate BETWEEN SS.EffectivityDate AND SS.EndDate
                    WHERE E.Status='1' AND E.ResignedDate IS NULL AND E.EmployeeID =    @EmployeeID        
       SET @StartDate = DATEADD(day,1,@StartDate)
      END       
    SET @StartDate   = @InitialDate -- Reinitialize Start Date
 FETCH NEXT FROM Employees INTO @EmployeeID, @BranchCode,@IsOfficer,@FirstName, @MiddleName, @LastName, @RankCode;
 END;
```

CLOSE Employees;
DEALLOCATE Employees;

With this solution, if we are going to run the script. it took 3 minutes and sometimes 6minutes.

Might be the structure

Dates ('11/1/2015' - '11/30/2015')
 -> Attendance
 -> LeaveHistory

All dates from Dates table in date range will be filled with values from different table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Don't use cursor.In fact it can be done without using RBAR/cursor.

   2. You need to explain little more your table structure.Or start slowly with fewer column and table and ask where you are struck.
   3. Calender Table is not require.What is the purpose of "ShiftSchedule" ?
   4. You can do so by using recursive CTE.
   5. Tell us more then we help you accordingly.

Recursive CTE sample.you can implemented your example here with fewer table and column then gradually increase.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '11/1/2015'
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '11/30/2015';

WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT @StartDate DT

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, DT)
    FROM CTE
    WHERE DT < @EndDate
    )
SELECT *
FROM CTE
```

Comment: Thank you Sir. This solves my problem. I have deleted my Calendar table and use your code. And the problem has been solved. Thanks again. :)